# Alternative Toggle function Fires 2 functions Jquery

Tags: jquery, function, toggle

I have `jQuery 1.10.2`

```
$('.bot').toggle(

    function() {
        $(".bot").addClass("animateBot");
        $(".bot_shadow").addClass("animateShadow");
    },

    function() {
        $(".bot").removeClass("animateBot");
        $(".bot_shadow").removeClass("animateShadow");
    }
);

});
```

I found that it was depreciated. 
Is there any alternative solution for this?

Comment: use click event instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `click` and `toggleClass()`:

```
$('.bot').click(function () {
    $(".bot").toggleClass("animateBot");
    $(".bot_shadow").toggleClass("animateShadow");
});
```